# Likert plot 100 percent scale with Likert Package

Tags: r, plot, likert

I wanted to draw a likert plot with 100% scale (100) with equall plot size. I tried following code and give me following plot:

```
plot(LIKPR3,centred=TRUE,plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.neutral = TRUE, text.size = 6,
                  text.color = "black", include.center = TRUE,
                  ordered = TRUE, wrap = 60, wrap.grouping = 50, legend = "Response",
                  legend.position = "bottom", panel.arrange = "v",
                  plot.percent.low = FALSE, plot.percent.high = FALSE, central=FALSE)
```

[image: ss]

I would like to make plot similar to following.

[image]

I am using "likert" package in R.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hej,
the difference between the plot that you have created and the plot that you want to have is the "centre". With `centered = TRUE` you force the plot to be centred around the "neutral" category at 0, in case of a 5-point Likert scale this will be the third category. To obtain a stacked plot you have to use `centered = FALSE`.